# can I make a JavaScript code can take an Arabic Input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chatbot

I've been tying to create a chatbot and I did but I can't make him take the Input in Arabic,
anyone can help?

i tried what i can but it's not a lot because i'm still new in the field

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to explain your problem in more detail. Did you mean that you can't enter Arabic characters into the input? Or that the text direction is wrong? Or...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple input field to take Arabic input and it is working please check the code here :

```
<input type="text" id="arabic" value="اكتب في العربية">
<button onclick="func()">
button
</button>
<script>
function func(){
console.log(document.querySelector('#arabic').value);
}
</script>

live code: https://jsfiddle.net/6am57x1q/3/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwg0.png)